# Which rpm packages can be used to get system installation date

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I want to get the Linux installation date by the installed rpm packages. For example I can get the base rpm package rpm -qi basesystem. But it will be much more east for me if I can get another rpm package and read it's text log file for installation date. Are there any base package which I can use to read the Linux installation data.

Answer (score 1):

The package filesystem could also be used:

```
rpm -qi filesystem | grep "Install Date"
Install Date: Thu 24 Feb 2011 04:30:01 PM UTC      Build Host: build-31003.build
```

But it will not be useful if the host was cloned instead of installed.

I am telling this because if you try to determine installation date on a cloud provider using this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

To see the system installation date you can use these commands..

If you use ext2/ext3/ext4 then this command will provide you the results

`dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem created'`

/dev/sda1 is the main partition with boot loader

OR

`passwd -S root|tail -1|awk '{print $3}'`   This command provide result in yyyy-mm-dd

root is the name of the admin user.

AND

You can also use the command to check the first login time.

`last|grep 'wtmp'`